# React Redux удалить или вставить значение в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, redux

Условие: если значение, которое пришло в action уже есть в массиве - удаляем этот элемент из массива, если его нет - добавляем. Действие может происходить множество раз. Значений в массиве может быть сколько угодно, надо перебирать массив и искать совпадение. Пробовал так. В данном примере if не сработает никогда, только else

```
myArray: state.myArray.map(val => {
    if (action.actionVal.indexOf(val) > 0 ) {
        return state.myArray.splice(action.settingsId, 1);
    } else {
        return state.myArray.concat(action.settingsId)
    }
})
```

В итоге получаю это 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что map создает новый объект. Но что-то хоть как-то реагирующее мне написать не получилось.

Comment: Расскажите нам, что такое `state.myArray` и `action.actionVal`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko state.myArray - массив, который должен содержать значение. У меня чекбокс, при клике на него в myArray должно записаться значение(я указываю его в атрибуте функции).  А action.actionVal - сам ивент , то есть клик

Comment: Лушче выведите в консоль значения переменных и покажите. Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать reduce, а не map